# Vectors with 5-coordinates seemingly 3 Dimensional

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

[RREF of matrix A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brXNJ.png)

I have a theorem stating, that the non-zero-row-vectors of the row reduced echelon form of $A$ form the basis for the row-space of $A$.

As can be seen in the image I posted, the row vectors of $A$ contain $5$ coordinates. As an example the first row-vector: $(1,-3,2,2,1)$.

How come then, after I've $RREF(A)$, I only get $3$ non-zero-row-vectors as the basis for these? This means, that the vectors are 3D.

This goes against what I've been taught. That if we have a set of vectors S in $R^n \implies dim(S) = n$.

What is the explanation for this?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  The vectors are not linearly independent

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Oh, I see. What then has gone wrong, since the RREF(A) doesn't provide the basis for the row-space of A? This was stated as a proven-theorem, that the RREF(A) should provide the basis for the row-space of A.

Comment: @GeorgeWTrump: RREF(A) is a basis for the rowspace of A.  Your original description was not linearly independent, so the rowspace is not 5 dimensional.

Comment: To put it more succintly: "if we have a set of vectors $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n\Rightarrow\mathrm{dim}(S)=n$" is not true without further conditions.  Can you explain where you saw this/why you think it true?

Comment: @JacobManaker Oh okay, I did the determinant without transposing the row-space-basis-vectors, so it gave 0. I.e it wasn't linearly independent.

But, this was my first thought too. That there were a few vectors not "contributing" to the span, therefore not making it fully 5-dimensional. But then it seems that the dimension definition isn't the intuitiv understanding of 2- and 3D space?

My book (Howard Anton - Elementary Linear Algebra) states the following: "The standard basis for RÅn contains n vectors. Therefore every basis for R^n contains n vectors".

Comment: @GeorgeWTrump: That statement is correct.  Every basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ has $n$ vectors, but not every set of $n$ vectors is a basis!

Comment: @JacobManaker Right... 1) S = {all row-vectors of A}. 2) S is in R^5. 3) len(basis(S)) = 3 which is not equal to 5. Where len(x) = number of objects in x. How does this not go against the fact, that every basis of "R^n" has n vectors?

Comment: @JacobManaker Is it because I am not using standard basis...? If so, what is the point of defining dimension the way it is done, other than to communicate how large the basis of a vectorspace must be?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131134/discussion-between-jacob-manaker-and-georgewtrump).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From our discussion in chat, it seems like the key idea missing is the following:

Suppose you have a matrix, like so: $$M=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\2&0\end{bmatrix}$$  (I'm going to use $2\times2$ so that we can draw pictures.)  It's natural to want to study matrix multiplication involving $M$; indeed, $M$ defines a function $L^*_M$ sending a row vector $\vec{v}^*$ to $\vec{v}^*M$.<sup>Fn. 1</sup>

Since $L^*_M$ is defined on two-vectors and produces two-vectors, we can summarize it as sending $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$.  But this notation doesn't mean that $L^*_M$ hits everything in $\mathbb{R}^2$.  A useful analogy is $(\cdot)^2\in\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.  Taking squares sends real numbers to real numbers, but you can't produce a negative number this way.  We said $(\cdot)^2$ sends things to $\mathbb{R}$, because it produces real numbers — $\mathbb{R}$ intuitively seems like "a natural category of objects produced by my function."  The name for that sort of set is a *codomain*.

Conversely, the space of things $L^*_M$ does hit is called the *range* of $L^*_M$.

Indeed, if you compute $\vec{v}^*M$, you'll see that any such output must have second coordinate $0$.  So it isn't really a 2D object.  Instead, we *define* the dimension of a vector space to be the size of the any basis.<sup>Fn. 2</sup>  A basis for "elements of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with second coordinate $0$" is the single element $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\end{bmatrix}$, so we say that the range is 1D, even though the codomain (all of $\mathbb{R}^2$) is 2D.

Interestingly, the range of $L^*_M$ is also the row space of $M$.  *This is not a concidence!*  The row space of $M$ is the set of linear combinations of rows of $M$ and $$\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1&\lambda_2\end{bmatrix}M=\lambda_1\begin{bmatrix}1&0\end{bmatrix}+\lambda_2\begin{bmatrix}2&0\end{bmatrix}$$  You can always get the row space of a matrix this way.  So, to figure out the dimension of the row space, you need to do a little more than just "count the number of coordinates I wrote down."  One technique is to find a basis of the range of $L^*_M$ and (it turns out) RREF does this for you.<sup>Fn. 3, 4</sup>

In your example, $A$ is $5\times5$, so $L_A^*\in\mathbb{R}^5\to\mathbb{R}^5$.  Your codomain is 5-dimensional, but the range of $L_A^*$ is much smaller.  [Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B1%2C-3%2C2%2C2%2C1%7D%2C%7B0%2C3%2C6%2C0%2C-2%7D%2C%7B2%2C-3%2C-2%2C4%2C4%7D%2C%7B3%2C-3%2C6%2C6%2C3%7D%2C%7B5%2C-3%2C10%2C10%2C5%7D%7D) confirms your RREF calculation: the row space of $A$ — which is also the range of $L_A^*$ — is 3D, because it has a $3$-element basis.

---

<sup>Fn. 1</sup>: $M$ also defines a function $L_M$ sending a column vector $\vec{v}$ to $M\vec{v}$.  Most books use that definition first, but it isn't useful for studying the row space.

<sup>Fn. 2</sup>: It might not be obvious to you that any two bases have the same size.  The proof takes a couple lines, and the key fact is the [Steinitz exchange lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinitz_exchange_lemma).

<sup>Fn. 3</sup>: If you're confused about why, ask your linear algebra instructor.

<sup>Fn. 4</sup>: There are other techniques you'll learn later too.  The [rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem) is key, because it lets you count related objects instead.